# Build Xamarin.iOS Solution does not Create IPA

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops to build an iOS solution and I noticed that when I Copy files , after I have build the solution there is no IPA file .
I have checked the check box "Create App Package" but still the ipa is not build.

What settings am I missing??? I am new to azure devOps so your help is appreciated!

[image]

There is noti

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Comment: hi I will have to rename things and remove some stuff since I dont have authority to publish company stuff as it's confidential. do you happen to have a pipeline that builds ios that I can see. or I could extract the pipeline from appcenter because that one works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by redoing the steps and it worked.Not sure what I missed

Comment: I would argue that given the ambiguity it might just be best to delete this entire question.